# setOnClickListener does not work in android studio

Tags: java, android, methods, onclick, invoke

that is my code, very simple and basic
public Button btn1;
public TextView txt1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            txt1.setText("finalyyyyyyyyyyy");


        }
    });
```

and the error showing is:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
findViewById(R.id.txt1);
findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

you are getting the views from the `.xml` file but you are not actually assigning the value to any object... so when you try to call a method to the `btn1` it's null (empty) and throws an error

So just assign the value you are getting to the views objects like so:

```
txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

This will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Save the element in variable and set onClick method to that particular variable as below:

```
btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            txt1.setText("finalyyyyyyyyyyy");


        }
    });
```